# javascript - Break search query string into object

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build api query in client side by breaking the user input in search field into object.

Example,
Search query

```
arg1:"2 words" business corporate arg2:val2
```

Desired value

```
{
    arg1: "2 words",
    arg2: "val2",
    extra: "business corporate"
}
```

I tried doing this.

```
var query = initquery.split(' ');
var obj = {};
for(var i=0; i<query.length; i++){
    var s = query[i].split(':');
    if(s.length == 2) {
        initquery = initquery.replace(query[i], '');
        obj[s[0]] = s[1];
    }
}
obj.extra = initquery;
```

This does not handle string in quotes.

Comment: Will there be only arg1 and arg2 inside the string? Or other arg{i}:val{i}s are also possible?

Comment: Yes other args are also possible.

Comment: Stack Overflow requires that you do your own work. Posting a problem is not enough. Write code and ask questions about it.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a regular expression, but it will be complicated because of the optional quotes around the arg. You should probably try to write a more specific parser.

Comment: @Barmar without quotes is very simple to solve but those quotes are what made me ask this question here.

Comment: @Tomalak do you really think that this question is not worth asking?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that you *did no work*. You came here to grab copy-and-paste code. You came here to leech, not to learn.

Comment: @rosinghal Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Barmar, @rosinghal: Will this regex work to catch the quotes? `(arg\d:").*(?=")|(arg\d:.*)`. I am assuming there is only one digit following each arg immediately followed by :. And If the args are extracted, the rest should be straightforward, right?

Comment: You need to use `.*?` to make it non-greedy. And the non-quoted case should use `\w*` so it stops when it gets to the end of the word.

Comment: The hard part now is to get the "extra" stuff in between the args.

Comment: @rosighal: It would also help if you could set out some rules for the query structure, such as if there are forbidden characters. The way you have posed your question, the best approach would be to follow Barmar's advice and opt for a parser.

Comment: That would have been a bit better, but it still does not contain any attempt at the "quotes problem", which is the core of your question, after all.

Comment: Thanks for info @Tomalak, will keep it in mind for future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this:

```js
addEventListener('load', function(){

var wtf = 'arg1:"2 words" business corporate arg2:val2 arg3:"fixedIt"';
function customObj(string){
  var a = string.split(/\s+(?!\w+")/), x = [], o = {};
  for(var i=0,s,k,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    s = a[i].split(/:/); k = s[0];
    s[1] ? o[k] = s[1].replace(/"/g, '') : x.push(k);
  }
  o['extra'] = x.join(' ');
  return o;
}
console.log(customObj(wtf));

});
```

Comment: Thanks @PHPglue, works fine in initial testing. Will test more use cases and let you know.

Comment: `arg1:"2 words" business corporate arg2:val2 arg3:"notCatching"`

Comment: I think I fixed it?

Comment: @PHPglue: yes, I couldn't break it this time! Nice Regex!

Comment: I actually found another small problem. But I really think it is the OP's job to lay out a clear set of requirements so people know what they are dealing with. Anyways, the query `arg1:"2 words" business:corporate arg2:val2` breaks your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barmar for [this helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291390/break-search-query-attributes/43291836#comment73650617_43291390), I came up with this regex to catch the args (assuming they are followed by a single digit number and a colon):

```
var pattern = /((^|\s)arg\d:").*?(?=")"?|(\sarg\d:\w*)/g;
```

Extracting the rest of the query can be done through:

```
query.replace(pattern,"");
```

And then creating the final object should be straightforward. Still, given the complexities that could rise from sprinkling double quotes in the query string, you should consider writing a parser for your application.

**UPDATE:**
Updated the regex to match beginning of the string and only match `arg` after white space character.